# New EC2 instances launched with RunInstances use stale AMI from Launch Template , after aws Code Deploy updates the application in running instances

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I have an environment where I want to create new EC2 worker instances based on demand.
I created a Launch Template using a snapshot AMI of an existing instance, and then use this in a RunInstances call to spin up new EC2 instances.

Every time the application is updated, it is deployed to the running EC2s using AWS Code Deploy. The problem is any new EC2s created programmatically uses the original Launch Template which has a version of the older application in its image. So the new EC2s get the original snapshot of the application instead of the latest deployed version.

Is there a way to overcome this? (Basically apply the latest code deploy to the new instances or get an updated Launch Template with each deploy to use ...)

```
let params = {        
            MaxCount: count, 
            MinCount: 1, 
            LaunchTemplate: {
                LaunchTemplateName: "<original-launch-template>"
            },
            TagSpecifications: [{
                ResourceType: "instance", 
                Tags: [
                    { Key: "Name", Value : "<code-deploy-tag>"},
                ]
            }],
        }; 
    let data = await new AWS.EC2({ region: "<region>"}).runInstances(params).promise();
```

Comment: Can you write a script that pulls and installs the latest version, or must it always deploy via CodeDeploy?

Comment: changes to application code are pushed via CodeDeploy using CodePipeline against S3 source. It's when I create EC2s dynamically that I run into the problem of a stale AMI that it is getting created against. Only in this case do I need to check for and update the latest version manually.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than relying on the software that is installed on the AMI, you could use a User Data script that runs on startup to install/update the software.

That way, it will always obtain the latest version when a new EC2 instance is launched.

Comment: thanks, that's a good idea! I have been using EC2 UserData to run the AfterInstall hook shell scripts -(same as aws code deploy would run based off appspec.yml) it didn't occur to me that I could do a version check and install an update using the same mechanism. I'll look into it. Thanks.

Comment: Another interesting approach might be to follow the runInstances call (to create ec2 instances) with a createDeployment where I can target the latest deployment ID against the specific target Instances.There is a updateOutdatedInstancesOnly 
 member
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CodeDeploy.html#createDeployment-property
Will give that a try

Answer (score 0):

this worked

```
            let data = await ec2.runInstances(params).promise();
                    
           
            let result = await codeDeploy.createDeployment({
                  applicationName: '<name>', /* required */
                  autoRollbackConfiguration: {
                       enabled: true,
                       events: [
                           'DEPLOYMENT_FAILURE'
                       ]
                  },
                  deploymentConfigName: 'CodeDeployDefault.AllAtOnce',
                  deploymentGroupName: `<your-group-name>`,
                  fileExistsBehavior: 'OVERWRITE',
                  updateOutdatedInstancesOnly: true 
              }).promise();
```